# Expected legend item not selected when scroll bar is present when opening r-plotly markdown in Chrome

Tags: html, r, google-chrome, r-markdown, plotly

I have run into an issue with the HTML output produced when using a markdown 
 script to knit a plotly object. The issue appears to only occur when the produced HTML is opened in Chrome. When there are enough legend items that a legend scrollbar is needed than attempting to select a legend item does not select the intended item. Clicking a legend item results in highlighting or unhighlighting whatever item would be under the current mouse position if there was no scroll bar and instead all legend items were compressed into the viewable legend space. For example even with the legend scrolled all the way to the top, clicking near the bottom of the legend space will select the very bottom legend item, which is not currently visible. The more legend items the more off it gets.

How do I produce a legend with proper scrollable items when opened in chrome? The larger project will be used by an end user who's choice of browser I will have no control over.

Edit:
The plot thickens. I have found that the issue disappears if an additional browser window is open that also contains a plotly object if that object does not have a scrollbar in the legend. That is to say: with the issue actively occurring in one browser window by opening a second tab containing a plot without a legend scroll the legend in the first window (containing the scroll) begins operating as expected. The legend with the scroll continues to operate properly even after closing the second window but stops operating correctly if another window containing a plot with a legend scroll is opened (last opened dictates behavior).

The code below is a stripped down version but reproduces the same issue. This issue occurs regardless of using the Knit button in R-studio or using `render()` from a regular R script.

````
---
title: Failed legend
output:
  html_document
---

```{r message=FALSE, warning=FALSE, include=FALSE}
invisible({
  library(plotly)
  library(htmltools)
  library(knitr)
})
```

```{r echo=FALSE, warning=FALSE, comment=NA, results="asis", out.width='100%'}

df <- data.frame(NAMES=LETTERS[1:24],X=sample(1:15,24,T), Y=runif(24,1,3))


pm <- plot_ly(data = df)
pm <- pm %>% 
  layout(title="Test plot", legend=list(bgcolor = "#E2E2E2"))

pm <- pm %>%
    add_trace(y=~Y, x=~X, type="scatter", mode="markers", color=~NAMES, marker=list(size=7))

pm

```
````